# Can I use redirects in my RESTful API to alias user specific content

Tags: rest, browser-cache

I have a typical RESTful API that consist of a tree of resources that are available to everyone. They are structured like this:

```
/api
/api/games
/api/games/101
/api/games/101/boards
/api/games/101/boards/201
```

These all include public information and nothing user specific so that the responses can be cached effectively until the resources change.

Now I want to allow different actions to different users.
For example: User `Alice` can post boards in `game 101` but `Bob` can not.
So in the response from `/api/games/101` I have, among other information, a URL to available actions.
This url is `/api/games/101/actions` for all users, so the response `/api/games/101` can be cached.

Now `/api/games/101/actions` will redirect to a user specific URL where user specific actions are defined. either `/api/games/101/actions/alice` or `/api/games/101/actions/bob` depending on which user is authenticated in the request.

My question is if this i a good ide? Will there be a problem with caching in the browser if I change the authenticated user, since this is a per-authenticated-user cache, asuming the client is a html-webapp.

Comment: In general utilizing caching and using redirects is fully supported by REST, at least it should be. In regards to whether authenticated requests should be cacheable, the [general definition is that they aren't](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/Issues/cache-authentication.html), though this is always from a general-purpose client standpoint interacting with such a service. Whether you utilize a client or server cache that does cache such responses is up to you

Answer (score 0):

> My question is if this is a good idea?

Yes it is a good idea to have different resources (and different identifiers) for information that is different.  Although given the constraints on private caches defined by [RFC 7234](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7234#section-3.2), it may not make a useful difference.

Having different resources for each *role* might be more manageable, in the long term, than different resources for each authenticated user.

> Will there be a problem with caching in the browser if I change the authenticated user, since this is a per-authenticated-user cache, assuming the client is a html-webapp.

Private caches are permitted to re-use responses to authenticated requests, so there's always then potential for a problem when Bob and Alice share a web browser, but don't necessarily have access to the same resources.